# DropShadowPanel adapt to button template style

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using the UWP Toolkit's DropShadowPanel for apply a shadow effect on a Button control.

Here the documentation : [DropShadowPanel XAML Control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/dropshadowpanel)

The fact is i edited the button style's Template for Round borders but the DropShadowPanel doesn't follow the new Template :

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel BlurRadius="4.0"
                              ShadowOpacity="0.70"
                              OffsetX="5.0"
                              OffsetY="5.0"
                              Color="Black"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                              Margin="91,90,0,0"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button x:Name="button"
                Content="Button"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

And the result :

[image]

So i expect Something like :

[image]

Do you have any ideas or leads to a similar result ?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Regards

Comment: What did you use in your ButtonStyle1 to make it round?

Comment: I set CornerRadius property to 10 of the RootGrid then for the ContentPresenter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bit late but here is a `Button` style that gives you a rounded drop shadow. As I explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211031/dropshadowpanel-and-border-corner-radius#45211031), you will need to use a `Rectangle` inside the `ControlTemplate` to get the *alpha mask* for the shadow.

Note I had to create my own focus visual and turn off the system one 'cause the latter doesn't support rounded corners.

```
<Style x:Key="ShadowButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="#FF399C94" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="24,8" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight"
            Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                      Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundVisual"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundVisual"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"
                                                     d:IsOptimized="True" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"
                                                     d:IsOptimized="True" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual"
                               Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                               StrokeThickness="2"
                               RadiusX="12"
                               RadiusY="12"
                               Margin="-2"
                               Opacity="0" />
                    <controls:DropShadowPanel HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                              Color="Black"
                                              ShadowOpacity="0.8"
                                              OffsetY="4">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundVisual"
                                   RadiusX="12"
                                   RadiusY="12"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

... and this is how it looks like. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the panel works, but I'd try putting the panel inside of the button template, just around the Border that has the actual rounded corners. Otherwise - I'd just use a [`NineGrid`](https://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/09/21/image-ninegrid-in-winrt/) to implement the drop shadow.

Comment: Already tested without result expected. There is maybe a simple solution, i will continue to search. Thanks for your help.