# DropShadowPanel and border corner radius

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I want to make drop shadow effect with border control. I am using UWP toolkit.

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel x:Name="dspShadow"
                          BlurRadius="10"
                          ShadowOpacity="0.8"
                          OffsetX="0"
                          OffsetY="0"
                          Color="Black">
    <Border x:Name="borderMain" Background="Red" CornerRadius="10"/>
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

But it doesn't recognize corner radius, the result is like this:

[image]

And I need it to look like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mask it. Currently you can only get the mask from `TextBlock`, `Shape` and `Image`. In this case just replace the `Border` with a `Rectangle`.

```
<controls:DropShadowPanel x:Name="dspShadow"
                          BlurRadius="10"
                          OffsetX="0"
                          OffsetY="0"
                          ShadowOpacity="0.8"
                          Color="Black">
    <Rectangle Width="100"
               Height="48"
               Fill="Red"
               RadiusX="10"
               RadiusY="10" />
</controls:DropShadowPanel>
```

Comment: [Another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40719312/815938) for you to close. ;)

Comment: @kennyzx ha! Thanks! I wonder how two questions end up with the same images. lol...

Comment: I saw images on this link: http://techqa.info/programming/question/40719312/ so, that's why I guess.

Comment: If you are interested, also have a look at the answer I just posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719312/dropshadowpanel-adapt-to-button-template-style/45213416#45213416).

Comment: Thanks. But what about the grid?  I may need to apply column and row.